# Examples of servant pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns, command-pattern

Is there any [Servant pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_(design_pattern)) examples in PHP? It seems that it is not very popular pattern but I find it quite useful and it is simpler than the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Is it an anti-pattern?

I can find it is implemented in other languages such as in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_(design_pattern)#Example) (I don't know what language it is but looks like java).

My example:

```
// Servant.
interface Servant
{
    //  
}

// Servable.
interface Servable
{
    //
}

// Concrete Servable.
class ConcreteServable implements Servable
{
    private $position;

    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position . '<br/>';
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }
}

// Concrete Servant.
class ConcreteServant implements Servant
{
    // Method, which will move Servable implementing class to position where.
    public function moveTo(Servable $Servable, $arg) 
    {
        // Do some other stuff to ensure it moves smoothly and nicely, this is
        // the place to offer the functionality.
        $Servable->setPosition($arg);
    }
}

$ConcreteServable = new ConcreteServable();
$ConcreteServant = new ConcreteServant();
$ConcreteServant->moveTo($ConcreteServable, 10);
echo $ConcreteServable->getPosition(); // 10
```

But not sure whether I am doing it correctly or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Servant pattern isn't noticed as much as other patterns in PHP, but this is due to often taking place in services.
It isn't an anti pattern

In your example the interfaces don't specify any methods that a class must implement, the reason for the interface is to force the class to have the methods you are after.

I took the example of a Servant pattern found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_(design_pattern)#Example) and converted it to PHP for reference.

This does show a good example of how the Servant pattern for PHP, but I wouldn't use it for something this simple.

```
class Position {
    /** @var int  */
    public $x = 0;
    /** @var int  */
    public $y = 0;
}

interface PositionedInterface {

    public function getPosition(): Position;
    
    public function setPosition(Position $position): void;
}

class MoveServant {

    public static function moveTo(PositionedInterface $positioned, int $xMoveTo, int $yMoveTo): void
    {
        /** @var Position $newPosition */
        $newPosition = new Position;
        $newPosition->x = $xMoveTo;
        $newPosition->y = $yMoveTo;
        $positioned->setPosition($newPosition);
    }

    public static function moveBy(PositionedInterface $positioned, int $xMoveBy, int $yMoveBy): void
    {
        /** @var Position $startPosition */
        $oldPosition = $positioned->getPosition();

        /** @var Position $newPosition */
        $newPosition = new Position;
        $newPosition->x = $oldPosition->x + $xMoveBy;
        $newPosition->y = $oldPosition->y + $yMoveBy;
        $positioned->setPosition($newPosition);
    }
}

class Triangle implements PositionedInterface
{
    /** @var Position */
    private $position;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->position = new Position();
    }

    /**
     * @return Position
     */
    public function getPosition(): Position
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @param Position $position
     */
    public function setPosition(Position $position): void
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }
}

// Only fully typed out instead of extended to match example from link in question 
class Ellipse implements PositionedInterface
{
    /** @var Position */
    private $position;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->position = new Position();
    }

    /**
     * @return Position
     */
    public function getPosition(): Position
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @param Position $position
     */
    public function setPosition(Position $position): void
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }
}

// Only fully typed out instead of extended to match example from link in question 
class Rectangle implements PositionedInterface
{
    /** @var Position */
    private $position;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->position = new Position();
    }

    /**
     * @return Position
     */
    public function getPosition(): Position
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @param Position $position
     */
    public function setPosition(Position $position): void
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }
}
```

this would allow use of `MoveServant` on any class that implements the `PositionedInterface`

```
$myTriangle = new Triangle();
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->x = 0
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->y = 0

MoveServant::moveBy($myTriangle, 15, 30);
// $myTriangle->getPosition()->x = 15
// $myTriangle->getPosition()->y = 30

$myEllipse = new Ellipse();
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->x = 0
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->y = 0

MoveServant::moveBy($myEllipse, 20, 100);
// $myEllipse->getPosition()->x = 20
// $myEllipse->getPosition()->y = 100

MoveServant::moveBy($myEllipse, -18, -85);
// $myEllipse->getPosition()->x = 2
// $myEllipse->getPosition()->y = 15

$myRectangle = new Rectangle();
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->x = 0
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->y = 0

MoveServant::moveTo($myRectangle, 10, 20);
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->x = 10
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->y = 20

MoveServant::moveBy($myRectangle, 20, 10);
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->x = 30
// $myRectangle->getPosition()->y = 30
```